# Vector generated numpy column with values under condition

Tags: python, numpy, vector

Suppose I have a numpy array generated like so:

```
np.random.seed(1)
arr = np.random.randint(10,size=(5,2))
```

which produces the following:

```
array([[5, 8],
       [9, 5],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 7],
       [6, 9]])
```

How do I:

- add randomly a new column *with its own range* making sure that its values DO NOT match any values in the other columns? E.g. simply appending another array would not work because it would not guarantee *not* having duplicate values.

The following would be illegal because as we see in the first row, the third column is 8 where the second column is also 8:

```
np.append(arr, np.random.randint(10,size=(5,1)), axis=1)

array([[5, 8, 8],
   [9, 5, 8],
   [0, 0, 6],
   [1, 7, 2],
   [6, 9, 8]])
```

A sub-question:

- how do I generate another column with values that are distinct from select columns, e.g. it is OK for the value to be equal to the second column, but it is prohibited to match the first column.

I understand that this can be done using standard *for* loops, but this would dramatically decrease the performance if we are talking about millions of rows, so I am looking for a vectorized solution.

Comment: How random does it need to be? Can you just sum the other columns and add 1, for example? Can any of the values be negative?

Comment: It must be random within a new range, so summing up the other columns would not work, and negative might and might not acceptable depending on the circumstances.

Comment: When you mention "add randomly a new column with **its own range**", what do u mean by range here? Should it be [0,10] or [first_col_value, second_col_value] ?

Comment: Yeah, I am referring to an independent range [0,10], not first_col, second_col.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it;

```
import random

def my_randint(a, select_columns, n):
    integers = list(set(range(n)).difference(a[select_columns]))
    return random.choice(integers)

new_col = np.apply_along_axis(my_randint, axis=1, arr=arr, select_columns=[0, 1], n=10) 
new_arr = np.hstack([arr, new_col[:,None]])
```

Note that I use `random.choice` instead of `np.random.choice` because it is faster.

Comment: You rock, Andreas.